# fedora, tizen studio: "failed to start sdb", cannot connect tizen device

Tags: tizen, fedora-25, libcrypto, tizen-studio, tizen-sdb

It is just sharing of knowledge. I hope I saved someone's time.

## Problem description

If you have Fedora Linux (I use f25 now) but want to use [Tizen Studio](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/download) (officially it works only with Ubuntu Linux) you can face with these issues after installation and launch Studio:

- Error message "failed to start sdb" during every Studio start
- You can view Tizen devices from your network, but cannot connect

The problem is not started **sdb** tool (`~/tizen-studio/tools/sdb`)

For checking suspects you can try to launch `sdb`, it must failed with error: `sdb: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Then, if you will check `sdb` with `ldd` command, you will see that `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` is not found:

```
user@host$ ldd ~/tizen-studio/tools/sdb
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9dbf9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd8fc5be000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd8fc1f8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560aab3af000)
```

## The solution

Unfortunately, this problem cannot be solved with simple `symlink` to `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` and  on Fedora 25 (and, I suppose, on Fedora 23 and 24 also). So, the simplest way is to get this libs from Ubuntu repo. We need package `libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb` ([link for mirror.yandex repo](http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb)), but do not forget to choose your architecture. Extract this deb package and copy (as root user) files `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` and `libssl.so.1.0.0` to `/usr/lib64` (or `/usr/lib` for i686 arch). Then launch command `ldconfig` as root.

After these actions you can launch `sdb` command:

```
user@host$ ~/tizen-studio/tools/sdb version
Smart Development Bridge version 2.2.91
```

After re-launching Tizen Studio you will can connect to Tizen Devices.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When providing an answer to your own question, you can also use the "Answer your own question" checkbox below the question. This way, people can upvote your answer and you can mark your question as being answered. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @MichaelLihs I can not. From FAQ: [If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) But my reputation is less than 15 :) So, I even can not edit this comment and I have to perform a "delete-create" exercise.

Comment: upvoted so that you hopefully have enough reputation soon :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 20 I downloaded the `libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb` file from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download and installed via software install and worked

Answer (score 2):

It is much better to let your root partition untouched. You can write a script which preloads needed liraries and starts the sdb binary like this:

```
$ cd ~/tizen-studio/tools/
$ mv ./sdb sdb.bin
$ mkdir ./lib
$ mv libcrypto.so.1.0.0 ./lib/
```

then create a script named "sdb":

```
# sdb
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib/ ./sdb.bin "$@"
```

`$ chmod +x ./sdb` and you are all set!

Comment: It is good solution if you are not afraid that tizen studio upgrade overwrite your script.

Comment: Works fine only if called from the same directory. In order to work for Tizen Studio, I had to replace `./lib/` and `./sdb.bin` with absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use libraries from the Steam.

Here is my '/usr/local/bin/sdb' script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${HOME}/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
${HOME}/tizen-studio/tools/sdb "${@}"
```